# Can't enable JavaScript MLE on APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

I am running Oracle APEX 21.1 (build 21.1.3.r1531102) on the 21c express database and for some reason I cannot execute server side code with the JavaScript MLE option.

In the develpment environment it does not show the option at all.

In the SQL commands screen I can only execute pure sql or PL/SQL. If I try to execute the following example

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  ctx dbms_mle.context_handle_t;
  user_code clob := q'~
    console.log('Hello World!');
  ~';
BEGIN
  ctx := dbms_mle.create_context();
  dbms_mle.eval(ctx, 'JAVASCRIPT', user_code);
  dbms_mle.drop_context(ctx);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    dbms_mle.drop_context(ctx);
    RAISE;
END;
```

I get the following message:

```
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210100", line 673
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1703
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210100", line 659
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1854
```

Comment: Please try to run without the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` option. That option is not always available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few weeks ago we solved this and I forgot to update this question.

After some work we found out that user needed to be granted access to MLE. I was not that one who fixed, but I've asked the code to post here, check below:

```
GRANT MLE JAVA

GRANT EXECUTE DYNAMIC MLE to XYZ;

GRANT EXECUTE ON JAVASCRIPT TO XYZ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first line or comment this out, I suppose this is for on premise DB version support but not allowed in ADB.